# Is this a memory leak?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks

```
char *pointer1;
char *pointer2;

pointer1 = new char[256];
pointer2 = pointer1;

delete [] pointer1;
```

In other words, do I have to do `delete [] pointer2` as well?

Thanks!

Comment: As a rule of thumb, the # of `delete`'s should usually match the # of `new`'s.

Comment: You do not delete pointers, you delete the things they point to.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Nope, that code is fine and won't leak memory.

You only have to use delete[] once because you've only used one new to allocate an area for memory, even though there are two pointers to that same memory.

Comment: Correct. In fact you **must not** - attempting to `delete` the same memory block twice would lead to undefined behaviour.

Comment: It should also be noted that any attempt to deference `pointer2` will result in undefined behavior, as well.

Comment: side.. As you're learning.. I'd say it's a good idea to set pointer1 = NULL;  As a reflex to the delete.  I've seen a pile of code where the pointer is deleted but later the app does a if(pointer1)..

Comment: Unfortunately it would not help with `pointer2` here, a good guideline still.

Answer (score 7):

A simple rule: you need as many `delete`s as there are `new`s. Even better, use something like a smart pointer or a container to take care of it for you.

And another minor point: `pointer2` is becoming a "dangling pointer" once you call `delete` on `pointer1`.

Comment: Very true, but I thought it was more obvious :)

Answer (score 4):

It's not a leak, but it is asking for trouble.  `pointer2` is pointing to who-knows-what as soon as you delete `pointer1`.  It's what's called a "dangling pointer".  Using it can in the best case cause a segfault, and in the worst case can cause mysterious data mangling in anything that ends up allocated that same spot.

Answer (score 2):

While it doesn't leak memory, if you want to be explicit, you should set both `point1` and `point2` to NULL (and initialize them that way too.)

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, consider using `boost::shared_ptr<>` from the Boost libraries.  It's the greatest thing since sliced bread.

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<TypeX> StrRef;

foo() {
  StrRef pointer1(new TypeX);

  while(something) {
    StrRef pointer2 = pointer1;
    // do stuff
  }

 return;
}
```

The data (`TypeX`) will be deleted when the last pointer to it goes out of scope.  You can do something similar with the built-in `auto_ptr<>` type, if you don't need a reference count:

```
typedef auto_ptr<TypeX> StrRef;

foo() {
  StrRef pointer1(new TypeX);

  while(something) {
    TypeX * pointer2 = pointer1.get();
    subroutine(pointer2);
    if (condition) return;
  }

 return;
}
```

Whenever `pointer1` goes out of scope, it will delete the data.  The advantage with this is that you don't have to remember put a delete before the return statement at the bottom, and if `pointer1` goes out of scope for any other reason (i.e. return from the middle of the loop, or `subroutine()` throws an exception, then the data will still be deallocated properly.

I haven't tested this code, so you'll have to check the docs for `auto_ptr<>` and `boost::shared_ptr<>` yourself.

I highly recommend using the Boost libraries as much as possible.  It's written by pro's it's basically a staging area for extensions to C++.

Answer (score 1):

`delete` deletes the memory that was allocated by `new`. Since you only have one `new` you only need one `delete`.

Answer (score 0):

Only use Delete when you've used New

Good practive is to set pointer2 to NULL, but you won't have a memory leak if you don't

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not have to delete[] pointer2 because you have not allocated memory for it!

The statement `pointer2 = pointer1` makes `pointer2` point to the same memory address as `pointer1`, does not allocate any extra memory for it.

Comment: Um...`pointer2` points to the same address *as* `pointer1`, it does not point to the address of `pointer1` (address of `pointer1` would be `&pointer1`.

Comment: @Nathan Ernst: Sorry, I mistyped. Corrected

Answer (score 0):

Every `new` should have one, and only one, matching `delete`. If you deleted the other pointer, you would break that rule.

Answer (score 0):

What you do here is just tell that memory block allocated by `new char[256]` would be pointed by `pointer1` and `pointer2` at the same moment.

It would be a memory leak if you wrote `delete[] pointer2;` statement after.

Comment: It would be undefined behavior if he deleted pointer2. In practice, I don't know a single platform where it would result in a memory leak. Most likely, you'd get something like segfault/AV.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the gap in your thinking: You don't delete pointers — you delete memory. You simply use a pointer to identify the block of memory to be freed. Since the two variables point to the same memory, deleting one is precisely equivalent to deleting the other. In other words, deleting both is the same as deleting one of them twice — which is obviously wrong.